# Azure Table Storage for housing Application Configuration

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-table-storage, azure-keyvault

-- I am exploring Azure functionality and am wondering if Azure Table Storage can be an easy way for holding application configuration for an entire environment. It would be easy to see and change (adding list values etc.). Can someone please guide me on whether this is a good idea? I would expect this table to hold no more than 2000 rows if all our applications were moved over to Azure.

```
   Partition Key --> Project Name + Component Name (Azure Function/Logic App)

   Row Key --> Parameter Key

   Value column --> Parameter Value
```

-- For securing password/keys, I can use the Azure Key Vault.

Comment: There's really no "right" answer to this. Table Storage might work well for you, but how would you manage the lifetime of settings? (in other words: How will you version them, edit them, etc) - this is in contrast to a configuration file, which can be stored in something like git, and be updated over time with related history.

Comment: Good point David.

Comment: Looks like an Azure Storage Table can be exported to a CSV file using PowerShell and stored in git. (http://mmaitre314.github.io/2014/11/25/exporting-an-azure-storage-table-to-a-csv-file-using-powershell.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of storing application configurations:

1. Key Vault (as you stated) for sensitive information. Ex. tokens, keys, connection strings. It can be standardized and extended to any type of resources for ease of storing and retrieving these.
2. Application Settings, found under each App Service. This approach assumes you have an App Service for each of your app.
3. Release Pipeline, such as Azure DevOps Services (AzDo). AzDo has variables that can be global to the release pipeline or some that can be specific to each stages

Answer (score 1):

> I am exploring Azure functionality and am wondering if Azure Table
>   Storage can be an easy way for holding application configuration for
>   an entire environment. It would be easy to see and change (adding list
>   values etc.). Can someone please guide me on whether this is a good
>   idea?

Considering Azure Tables is a key/value pair store, it is certainly a good idea to store application configuration values there. Only thing I would recommend is that you incorporate some kind of caching layer between your application and table storage so that you don't end up making calls to table storage every time you need to fetch a setting.

> I would expect this table to hold no more than 2000 rows if all our
>   applications were moved over to Azure.

Considering the number of entities is going to be less than 2000, I think your design would have no impact in querying the entities however I think your design is good. For best performance, please ensure that you're including both PartitionKey and RowKey while querying. At the very least, include PartitionKey in your query.

Please see this for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide.

> For securing password/keys, I can use the Azure Key Vault.

That's the way to go for storing sensitive data in Azure.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav. Yes, I plan to use both the PartitionKey and RowKey for querying as only when used together are they unique in my design. Good point on the caching. I was thinking of getting all the configuration records for the logic app/azure function at the beginning of execution. is that good enough?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [App Configuration service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-configuration)?

There are client libraries in [.NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/appconfiguration/), [Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/appconfiguration/azure-data-appconfiguration), [TypeScript](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/appconfiguration/app-configuration) and [Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/appconfiguration/azure-appconfiguration) to interact with the service that you can leverage in your application.